# Iteratively update the values of a dataframe with another one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a main df:

```
print(df)

   item            dt_op     
0  product_1     2019-01-08   
1  product_2     2019-02-08    
2  product_1     2019-01-08        
...
```

and a subset of the first one, that contains only one product and two extra columns:

```
print(df_1)

   item            dt_op        DQN_Pred  DQN_Inv
0  product_1     2019-01-08         6      7.0
2  product_1     2019-01-08         2      2.0
...
```

That I am iteratively creating, with a for loop (hence, `df_1 = df.loc[df.item == i] for i in items`).

I would like to merge `df_1` and `df`, at every step of the iteration, hence updating df with the two extra columns.

```
print(final_df)

   item            dt_op      DQN_Pred  DQN_Inv
0  product_1     2019-01-08       6      7.0  
1  product_2     2019-02-08      nan      nan
2  product_1     2019-01-08       2      2.0     
...
```

and update the nan at the second step of the for loop, in which `df_1` only contains `product_2`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please see [pandas-merging-101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
final_df=df_1.combine_first(df).reindex(columns=df_1.columns)
```

---

```
        item      dt_op  DQN_Pred  DQN_Inv
0  product_1 2019-01-08       6.0      7.0
1  product_2 2019-02-08       NaN      NaN
2  product_1 2019-01-08       2.0      2.0
```

Alternatively, Using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) , you can use the common keys with `left_index` and `right_index` =`True`:

```
common_keys=df.columns.intersection(df_1.columns).tolist()
final_df=df.merge(df_1,on=common_keys,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left')
```

---

```
        item      dt_op  DQN_Pred  DQN_Inv
0  product_1 2019-01-08       6.0      7.0
1  product_2 2019-02-08       NaN      NaN
2  product_1 2019-01-08       2.0      2.0
```

Comment: The first method does not work iteratively, meaning that as soon as the loop reaches the second step, nan are replaced but the remaining values become nan ;  the second ones duplicates columns (DQN_Pred_x, DQN_Pred_y etc.)

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli i dont know what you mean, if you can create an example which best describes your issue, that'd be helpful. iterations are generally not preffered in pandas

Comment: combine first works, I was resetting df_1's index at every iteration (maybe specify that the index in the subset df must not be reset); however, the second seems to not be working. Thank you :)